# How to identify the binary compression type from the content?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, compression, gzip, binary-data

I am trying to restore files which are stored in MS SQL database (used by third party application which has stopped their support) as an image data type(byte arrays). So what I do is to write those rows of byte arrays to file to convert for know file extensions. However some of them are not known which I believe they are compressed. Since I get "CC_Compress" string and random characters in the file after conversion. I was wondering if it is possible to find out which compression method were used and how can I decompress it before I convert them.

Following is first bytes from the byte array: 
0x43435F434F4D50524553530000000000000000000000010004F60000E4780000EC7C075C54C7F3F85CA10A8A204544796001519A0D4569414414011115238A079C80C21D5204224D632C51C19268628FC6A851638B9A88882D9604C5D83BB688A002564085FBCFBEBDC71DCD16623EFFEF2FA373B33B5B667676B6BC7DCB3B9DDFF2E677DB8D6F411D70060154CB34401514C043D4E5223A00AD80F2AA65321961B54494FD07FF5FC1C3750741304E430850A19B0B2CE8B0BFD8F16DD5019A43C88490097FC4FD1107F5404368003D740036B6E6B1D816DE0C32598BB78639F89EFDDD20801AAA1C6E8CB60205E

and 43435F434F4D5052455353 is the part that converts to CC_Compress

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you provide an example with the first 30 or so bytes in hexadecimal, we might be able to help.

Comment: Haven't seen that before.  It has a long, mostly useless header.  Maybe the compressed data starts at the E478.  Can you provide another 30 bytes starting from there?

Comment: i added some more bytes. btw thanks for being involved to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw deflate-compressed data begins 32 bytes in (starting with the `ec 7c`).  You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to decompress it.

Comment: thank you very much that worked. what about bytes starting with ec 9d? can it be decompressed by zlib as well?

Comment: There is no magic prefix for raw deflate data.  If you don't know where the deflate data starts, then you just have to start inflating at every byte until you find one that goes for a while and successfully completes.

Comment: Oh I see, what can I do if I need to automate the process? Because i have lots of those binary data in database. Is there any pattern that I can search for?

Comment: No.  The only pattern is that the deflate stream is valid and terminates.  Your data may have a pattern in the header.  Maybe it always starts 32 bytes in. Maybe there is some data in the header that points to the start of the deflate stream.  That's where you should look for a pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much again, I really appreciate it, helped a lot. Btw voted as useful answer and marked it as correct :)

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue. I wrote a little program to try to inflate at each byte and see how far it goes. But with the input show in the question, I don't find any valid deflate streams. And when I try to use zlib to start inflating at byte 32, I get 0 output. What am I missing?

Comment: @Flecto You are likely not requesting raw inflation using `inflateInit2()`.